# PayPal adding extra taxing to Magento Cart on PayPal side

Tags: magento, paypal

I am having an issue with Magento.

After launching the site live for customers, everything was ok for 11 days. Yesterday, one of the customer informed us that their payment has been flagged as suspected as fraud. We went to check and saw that the amount on Magento site and PayPal  differed. After checking through the reason, we saw that PayPal is adding another tax to the amount transferred from Magento even though Magento has already included all the amount.

This is the error that I am getting when I changed to PayPal express checkout.

PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check my answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804883/suspected-fraud-status-after-compeleting-the-payment-in-magento/44993619#44993619](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804883/suspected-fraud-status-after-compeleting-the-payment-in-magento/44993619#44993619)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Not sure this is the best way to do it. But, it works.

Just to clarify, I want to use PayPal web standard with Magento.

\app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Api\Standard.php

I commented out the follwing.

```
49 //  'tax'           => 'tax_amount',

65 //'tax'      => '_filterAmount',

93 //Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart::TOTAL_TAX      => 'tax',
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested you log what was posted to Paypal against what went into paypal order related DB.

Use similar details to what was there for that specific case.

Probably some code of yours( additional module )  added tax in paypal form that was posted where this addiitonal amount didnt update order total so order details were intact.

Comment: I suspect it was due to some extensions that I added after implementation for the admin module. Uninstalling those extensions however did not help the situation.

Comment: Unless you log whats posted to paypal and compare with what has gone into order will be difficult to conclude where issue occurred was it something wrong with your account configuration in paypal or something wrong with Magento code.